# Ordered rings $R$ with $ab = ba$, $ab \leq ba$ or $ba \leq ab$ for all $a, b \in R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Ordered rings $R$ with $ab = ba$, $ab \leq ba$ or $ba \leq ab$ for all $a, b \in R$?

Are there any good examples that are not also commutative rings? I can't seem to think of any.

Comment: The last trichotomy case should be $ab \ge ba$ (it was OK in the title, but at this time it's not right in the body of question.)

Comment: You mean $\forall a,b\in R\colon ab\le ba$? Well, then $R$ is necessarily commutative because $ab\le ba\le ab$ implies $ab=ba$.

Comment: I think it means, for any *fixed* pair $a,b$ one of the three options holds. In other words OP wants an ordered noncommutative ring (with the order satisfying trichotomy).

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to ask $a = b, a \le b, a \ge b$?

Comment: Sorry - I meant what I put in the title. Although now that I think about it again I guess its the same thing as Qiaochu suggests.

Comment: This question has appeared on this site before, and in the accepted example a noncommutative ordered ring is explained. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621111/existence-of-non-commutative-ordered-ring